# module "time" has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am stuck in this error, i know the function "clock" has removed, but the problem is, i cant find the function code in the code
code:

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from skimage.transform import resize
from IPython.display import HTML
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

source_image =imageio.imread(r"C:\Users\jpdyb\Documents\first-order\workspace\02.png")
reader =imageio.get_reader(r"C:\Users\jpdyb\Documents\first-order\workspace\04.mp4")


#Resize image and video to 256x256

source_image = resize(source_image, (256, 256))[..., :3]

fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']
driving_video = [r"C:\Users\jpdyb\Documents\first-order\workspace\04.mp4"]
try:
    for im in reader:
        driving_video.append(im)
except RuntimeError:
    pass
reader.close()

driving_video = [resize(frame, (256, 256))[..., :3] for frame in driving_video]

def display(source, driving, generated=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8 + 4 * (generated is not None), 6))

    ims = []
    for i in range(len(driving)):
        cols = [source]
        cols.append(driving[i])
        if generated is not None:
            cols.append(generated[i])
        im = plt.imshow(np.concatenate(cols, axis=1), animated=True)
        plt.axis('off')
        ims.append([im])

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.close()
    return ani


HTML(display(source_image, driving_video).to_html5_video())
```

error (python):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\Documents\first-order\python system\load images.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython.display import HTML
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: Must be ancient version of IPython installed.  Upgrade it.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  The git repo goes back to 2010, and it older than that.